# Is it possible to make SVN ignore changes in character case?

Tags: svn

We have VB6 application in a SVN repository and VB6 has the annoying habit to globally change the character case of same identifiers, thus creating many pseudo-conflicts.

Is it possible to make SVN ignore such changes?

We also have Java projects, so it must be a per-repository setting.

Comment: Is your question about file names or file contents?

Comment: File contents (identifiers, i.e. variables, types, ...)

Comment: It kind of defeats the purpose of a version control system if you're going to ignore changes of this nature. No? What if a case-change is deliberate?

Comment: VB6 really does have a habit of making arbitrary changes to case of code even in unrelated functions. For example it'll change .Name to .name when you edit a completely different property for seemingly no reason, or change the case of function parameters on functions you haven't been editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have SVN use an external diff tool to do diffs and merges, which could ignore whitespace. For example, the "diff" command on Unix has an --ignore-case option to ignore case.

Beware though, this will ignore case changes even when these are significant for VB, for example inside of strings.

A better option would probably be to standardize on whatever capitalization VB6 is trying to force on you (or turn off that option in VB6, if it as one), so that it isn't changing it in existing files all the time.

Answer (score 2):

The diff is performed locally so every client can decide its strategy. You can configure a local diff tool. Windows and unix versions how to do this are described in the [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html).

You can use this with unix:

```
svn --diff-cmd "./idiff.sh" diff
```

**idiff.sh :**

```
#!/bin/sh

LEFT=${6}
RIGHT=${7}

diff -i $LEFT $RIGHT
```